# Help with 16:1 Mux IC Wiring

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

I have these ICs

[image]

and I want to wire them like the sparkfun 16:1 mux breakout board.
Here is what I have so far. Is this correct?
[image]
 However I feel like these are not the same as the actual ICs. Also another quick question, how many of Mux can I daisy chain?
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes, is the circuit correct to the document?

Comment: You need to connect the EN pins on the mux chips.

Comment: @RoomofR: Welcome to EE.SE. Questions (and answers) here are supposed to have enough information in them that they are still useful when the links die. You can copy in text, illustrations or screengrabs to improve your question. Most of the busy guys (the experts) won't have time to follow your links.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the suggestion, I will fix the question.

Comment: What do you mean by " I feel like these are not the same as the actual ICs"?

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @RoomofR: Good job. You've got a good answer below already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is what I have so far. Is this correct?

Looks fine to me. Another option would be to share the COM pins and drive EN on the multiplexers to read from one at a time, but what you have is fine.

> However I feel like these are not the same as the actual ICs.

[The Sparkfun breakout boards you're referring to](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9056) are essentially "pure"  breakouts. The only additional things on the breakout board are:

1. A pulldown resistor on the EN pin, which is unnecessary if you're driving that pin, and
2. A decoupling capacitor on VCC, which you should have in your circuit as well. (Just connect a small ceramic capacitor between the VCC and GND pins on each IC -- 0.1 µF is about right.)

> How many of Mux can I daisy chain?

Plenty. :) You'll run out of input pins on the Teensy long before you hit any fundamental limitations of the multiplexer.

Comment: Re daisy chain issue will also be fan-out of the teens address lines though.

Comment: Both the Teensy and 74HC4067 are CMOS devices. Driving a dozen or two CMOS loads at reasonable speeds shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: A 3-to-8 line decoder controlling the EN pins with COM lines all tied together would let you drive 16x8 inputs with 4+3 outputs and 1 input.